# Connect to Azure Blob from PCL that targets Xamarin

Tags: .net, xamarin, azure-blob-storage, portable-class-library

I have a PCL Project (profile 78) for Xamarin, and tried to add this SDK (https://github.com/zgramana/azure-sdk-for-net) to connect to Azure Blob.

but got this error:

> Install-Package : Could not install package
>   'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager 1.8.0.0'. You are trying
>   to install this  package into a project that targets
>   'MonoAndroid,Version=v3.1', but the package does not contain any
>   assembly references or  content files that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author. At line:1
>   char:1
>   + Install-Package WindowsAzure.Storage
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

Answer (score 1):

The WindowsAzure.Storage library (as well as most of its dependencies) doesn't support Portable Class Libraries.  You could try to convert it to a PCL (probably a lot of work), or you could just recompile it for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android separately (probably not as much work) and put it behind an abstraction if you want to use it from a PCL.

Answer (score 0):

Someone over at the Xamarin forums [posted source code](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/22670/is-it-possible-to-use-microsoft-azure-storage-services) that's PCL compliant - I'm using it to upload .jpegs to Azure from my PCL project, does the job for me.